# Configuration() class is abstract can't be instatiated

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, sessionfactory

When I using Configration class to build sessionFactory it said the class is abstract can't be instatiated and want me to implement method getAppConfigurationEntry that return AppConfigurationEntry[] !!!

This is my code :

```
public class BookDAOImp implements GeneralDAO<Book, String> {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public BookDAOImp() {
    }

    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Can you help me with this little misunderstanding ?
can any body help me to build sessionFactory with this function or any method other ?

Comment: Configuration configuration = new Configuration(); -> change 'new Configuration();' to 'new <ClassThatExtends>Configuration();'

Comment: The problem still found because this class is abstract it want me to ovrride method ' getAppConfigurationEntry ' that return AppConfigurationEntry[]

Comment: well ... duh. you can only use abstract classes by extending them, and then you'll have to provide an implementation for the abstract methods

Comment: Good so how will build sessionFactory with this method 'getAppConfigurationEntry'

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.html#getAppConfigurationEntry(java.lang.String)